# Error while downloading Android SDK Tools

Tags: eclipse, adt, android-sdk-2.1, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install Android SDK Tool(Revision 20) . However, as shown in attachments, it always fails after reaching 59%.

I have already updated my ADT plugin to 20.0.3 as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html)

[image]

It then finishes with this error :-

```
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 20
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 90245472 bytes, got 54106132 bytes.
```

Also, I wish to know if there is some bug in this version, how can I switch back to my older SDK tool version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem occurs mostly due to slower internet connection.

You can do this as a workaround

- Download Android SDK Tools Rev. 20 (Which is the latest one) from http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r20.0.3-windows.zip
- Copy it to `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp` then try to install the package from Android SDK Manager. That way, it won't download the file as it is already there in the temp folder. It would just extract and install it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Was still downloading same bad file when attempting to do this, from sdk -> Tools -> Options clear cache and then I tried to install again and it worked

Comment: Basically just go to your C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp folder and whatever zip file you find there download manually from http://dl.google.com/android/repository/WHATEVER_ZIP.zip . This runs about 100 times faster than through sdk manager... When you downloaded everything, just go back to sdk manager and re-start the installation process